# How to run a Linux Terminal command at startup

Tags: linux, command, startup, raspberry-pi

I like to start my Siriproxy server on my Raspberry Pi on startup. I have to type

1. `cd siriproxy`
2. `rvmsudo siriproxy server`

in the Terminal to start the Siriproxy.
Is there a way to run the command on the startup?

Thanks a lot,

David

This is the script I edited:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

#I added this line
/home/pi/siriproxy server

exit 0
/etc/init.d/cron start
```

Comment: Consider creating a script in `/etc/init.d`.

Comment: @devnull No, cause I don't know how to do this and I am new to Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You can add commands that are run as root to the /etc/rc.local script, and they will then be run at boot-up. (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1822137)

From a terminal on your raspberry pi, run:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Add the following before the exit 0 line:

```
/path/to/siriproxy server
```

You can get the path of siriproxy by typing

```
which siriproxy
```

or depending on how your pi has siriproxy installed, it could be the full path of whatever you cd'd to, then adding "siriproxy" to the end.

Save the file and reboot to see it work! Hope this helped.

Comment: Hm, it wont work, please check ma original post, I added the script I have now.

Comment: does running `sudo (or rvmsudo) /home/pi/siriproxy server` from a command line work for you? After that what happens- does it release the terminal back to you so that you can continue issuing commands, or is it captured by siriproxy?

Comment: @mhOOh If I type rvmsudo /home/pi/siriproxy server I get Permission denied

Comment: It sounds like your problem isn't in the init script, but being able to run siriproxy to start with. What do you do to get it to start in the past? This isn't any different than cd'ing to the directory and then running the command. Did it work for you before, and does it now?

Comment: It worked before and now with the commands i posted in the main Post. My problem is that I have to cd in the siriproxy directory and then execute rvmsudo siriproxy server to start the proxy

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
screen -S ttlp
cd /home/pi/siriproxy
```

then

```
rvm siriproxy server
```

I haven't tried this yet, I will install it on one of my Pi's and help you.

Regards,
IC0NIC